# Sharepoint 2010 open list with access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I try open the sharepoint list with Access but result this error. Why? Anyone can help me? How i fix this?
[image: I try open the sharepoint list with Access but result this error. Why? Anyone can help me? How i fix this?]

English Translation:
Failed to export to the database. To export a list, and must have an application compatible with Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation.

Comment: Are you trying to link to a Sharepoint List?

Comment: @HK1 i am trying export sharepoint list data to another sharepoint list, in another site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hotfix for this issue, which was caused by Office SP2. Check the microsoft site to find the one you need for your configuration.